# UITextView did finish change selection

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, uitextview

I want to catch event when user finish change selection in UITextView. Method `textViewDidChangeSelection:` call a few times while user pulls cursor. I try to use `touchesEnded:withEvent:`, but it doesn't call. Try to add pan gesture, but pan handler don't call.

Comment: Please explain why you can't use `textViewDidChangeSelection:`.

Comment: Every time when selection changed I send request to server. I get a lot of requests in this case. I can send request with delay, it's plan B =)

Comment: It may be a good idea to do after waiting for some time after the last  `textViewDidChangeSelection:` call.

Comment: Yes, but I think it will be much much better if I will do it without delay. Response come within 0.1 second, it really fast. With delay users will be waiting ten times more that needs. And I have limit for requests per day. Anyway much better do without delay.

Comment: @Gralex Did you find a solution?

Comment: @webmastx I just use timer. If user change selection, invalidate previous timer and start new one. This works fine for my app.

Comment: @webmastx is right answer not working for you? Id don't remember if I check it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`UITextInputDelegate`'s `selectionDidChange(_:)` is called when the user has finished changing the selection (lifts their finger from the selection handles). On the `UITextView`, set your class as the `inputDelegate`. This works for read-only text views, not just editable ones.

Comment: I am using selectionDidChange with a UITextView and it seems to get called everytime i highlight an extra character rather than at the end of a block of text. So how is it different to textViewDidChangeSelection?

Answer (score 4):

I know it's too late to answer.
Though..
You can use `selectedRange` inside `textViewDidChangeSelection:` and check if `selectedRange.length` is greater than zero. This will confirm that user has selected something and not just moved the cursor.

Comment: Never too late to answer! StackOverflow is meant to be an archive reference for future searches as well, thank you!

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw exactly bro, the same happened to me.

Comment: I later could find the solution and posted it.

Comment: You missunderstand me. I want to handle when user finish select range. Every time when user move start range cursor event is called. Every time `length` > 0. I need somehow handle when user touch up his finger.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to subclass `UITextView` and implement `touchesEnded:withEvent:` in order to know when the user stops changing the selection.